# In TypeScript, can you type dynamic keys based on enum that are optional?

Tags: typescript, dynamic, enums

I'd like to be able to do this so that I have some code completion for the positions like theHistory.CEO but it keeps complaining that theHistory:LeadershipHistory doesn't have ALL the enum keys: CEO, CTO, CRO, CFO....

Is it even possible to have an enum for dynamic property keys?

```
type LeadershipHistory = Record<CxoPosition, LeadershipHistoryItem>;

type LeadershipHistoryItem = Record<string,{
    name: string;
    startDate: Date;
    endDate: Date;
}
>;

enum CxoPosition {
CEO = "CEO",
CTO = "CTO",
CRO = "CRO",
CFO = "CFO",
}

const theHistory:LeadershipHistory = {
    'CEO': {
        '234231343': {
            name: 'asedrftyu',
            startDate: '10/10/2010',
            endDate: '10/10/2010',
        },
        '76545675': {
            name: 'asedrftyu',
            startDate: '10/10/2010',
            endDate: '10/10/2010',
        }
    }
}
```

> Type '{ CEO: { '234231343': { name: string; startDate: Date; endDate: Date; }; '76545675': { name: string; startDate: Date; endDate: Date; }; }; CTO: { '989887787': { name: string; startDate: Date; endDate: Date; }; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'LeadershipHistory': CRO, CFOts(2739)

Comment: Wrong sample....ignore the fact that dates can't be strings.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBAZEBDAJiGAZwAsBLCACVMLlmQQF4EAlEAY1lwB4BhMKAApRCpOKSgA7ADSYc+ImUrVaMZAEk4IALYA+ANzBQkWIhRpZeAiXJUadDdsYt2nLsAQeENGKQkBzKXdPAG8gz08JbC0QAC4vOB9-A3Dwmmx4ABFsTTiszWSUjxAJXDzYhDKCjwBfYH1DI2h4BGKAVy0EPkFhUXEJBFDwngBRAHknACIR0YnAoYAVcaYpxdmwzuYlhCnNtaGAMS2pw7Xa4A4JGiRiEFsVZDisSwUbZTonQc8AcmmvuM-Cl8AEwAZgALKCAIzgkF-AbrQoeSLROJfbDojHor5zRGpODpOBlOISEAAdwq2RAAAoAJQ43FFEpEhAk8llWn0lLVTnhL4AdgAbABWMFCgV8oVwgEM5HlL4AI0VSsV2IRiLSmUpxLJFM0HLVhWKpS1LJ17LpBoQtXC3PWP0WUstXwAnAAON2uvl8z2OhkRKJythB4NB1V+jwawkm1m66kW8MtJnRs2U-W462eW3VIA

Comment: Are you just looking for `Partial` as in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mZykoN)?

Comment: @jcalz You nailed it. Thank you!